# unable to write right code for subscribe to the observable?

Tags: angular

Below is my code and just tell me where I am wrong?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})
export class BsNavbarComponent {
user:Observable<firebase.User>
  constructor(private afAuth :AngularFireAuth) 
  {
    afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => this.user = user);
   }

 logout(){
   this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
 }

}
```

I am just getting error at code inside constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've typed the user as `user:Observable<firebase.User>`, however by setting it inside the subscribe, it's no longer an Observable. Instead, you should change the type to `user: firebase.User`

```
user: firebase.User;

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) 
{
    afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => this.user = user);
}
```